# Holoviews additional hover values for Plotly backend

Tags: python, holoviews

Using Holoviews, does anyone know how I can pass specific `hover_data` through to `plotly` (e.g. https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting)? Should I use hooks (not quite sure how)?

I am trying to get Scatter3D to show more that the 3 axis values when hovering. Holoviews Plotly backend does not work with the hover tool so the usual method of passing it through the `vdims` does not work. (Of course, tell me what to search for if I should have found this out without asking here.)

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('plotly')

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': [1, 2, 3], 'h': ['one', 'two', 'three']})


# This will not work
hv.Scatter3D(df, kdims=['x', 'y', 'z'], hover_data=['h'])
```

Comment: Hooks do not work with Plotly but only `matplotlib` backend.

Comment: It may not be possible right now, could you file an issue about both hooks and hover control? We can add an answer here once it's been merged.

Comment: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4140 for hover data